# Convert from 'float' to 'int'?

Tags: mysql, int, type-conversion

I have a table with more than 1 million records, in 2 columns with datatype `varchar(50)` I have values like 23.23.

I need to convert the data/values to `int`.
For Example, 23.23 to 23 by remove the floating points.

I don't have primary key on this table.

Comment: pls try to give me right instruction for the title and comments, your asking `CONVERT` in the title,. but you finally accepting the answer for `ALTER`, they are confused, look at they answers like **(Saravanan, Raging Bull, Neels)**...

Comment: Dear jmail, my requirement was converting but alter table solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE <column_name> <column_name> <type>
```

**note:** you have to write column name twice
OR

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY <column_name> <type> ;
```

#### [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: @jmail What should i need to give demo in sqlfiddle

Comment: if he want those values permanently then he need to alter otherwise just convert

Answer (score 4):

You can use `FLOOR`:

```
SELECT FLOOR(columnName) 
FROM TableName
```

`Floor` returns the largest integer value not greater than X.

Read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_floor).

To convert the datatype of the field:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE columnName newColumnName targetFieldType;
```

Comment: I know the FLOOR, but how to do the conversion, any tip?

Comment: Do you want to convert the datatype of the field to int?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT ROUND(5.693893);

SELECT FLOOR(7.55);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try casting this field to a Decimal.

`SELECT CAST(field AS DECIMAL(10,0)) FROM table;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. My table has a field that is of type 'float' which I needed to be of type 'int'.

Thanks to Neels!

So, I had to first convert the field to be of type DECIMAL with 10,0 (no value after decimal) and then convert the field to be INT with length 11 for example.

ALTER TABLE `track` CHANGE `type` `type` DECIMAL(10,0);

ALTER TABLE `track` CHANGE `type` `type` INT(11);

Answer (score -1):

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE columnname columnname INT
```